# Help on adding a if controller login Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a set of variables which will populate from previous API calls.
And variables are looks like, which will go up to 12.

```
${V_ProductCode_1} 
${V_ProductCode_2} 
${V_ProductCode_3} 
${V_ProductCode_12}
```

I need to do the next API call if these variables are not null.
So to check that, I have added one if controller for each request.
But is there any way to simplify this approach.

This is what I have on my if condition.

```
"${V_ProductCode_1}"!=""
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about placing it under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with 12 iterations?

You will need to amend your condition a little bit to look like:

```
"${${__V(V_ProductCode_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)})}}"!=""
```

Where:

- `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` - pre-defined variable which returns Loop Controller's current iteration (starting from 0)
- [`__intSum()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) - JMeter function used to increment the value of the current loop by 1
- [`__V()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) - JMeter Function allowing evaluation of nested JMeter Functions and/or variables, see [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more information